# whats is the difference between regsvr32 and GAC?

Tags: gac, regsvr32

Whats is the difference between regsvr32 and GAC?

Of course regsvr32 is for COM and GAC is for .net assemblies but is that the only difference?

Comment: not only, the're organized differently too :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[regsvr32](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/regsvr32.mspx?mfr=true) is a program which is used to self-register dlls.

The [GAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1d93sz%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) is a versioned store for .Net assemblies.

They're not really comparable.